# What to use in Kotlin/Java for effective float collections handling?

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, memory

I'm working on an audio editing app, and I need to store the samples as floats in an efficient way - memory as well as performance-wise. Right now I'm using simply Kotlin's List, but I've heard about potential gains from using FloatArray type. I made a synthetic test to see the benefits and the results are a bit weird. Any advice on the techniques and collections I should use for large datasets of this nature could earn you a cookie, if I had one and knew your location.

So I have two alternative channel implementations (as in - channel in an audio file), to hold my data.

Here is my code for the channel based on FloatArray:

```
class ArrayChannel {

    private var mData : FloatArray = FloatArray(0)
    private var mLastWrittenIndex = 0

    fun getSamples(startIndex : Int = 0, endIndex : Int = mLastWrittenIndex) : FloatArray 
        = mData.sliceArray(IntRange(0, endIndex - 1))

    fun insertSamples(samples : FloatArray, startIndex : Int = mLastWrittenIndex) {
        if (mData.size - mLastWrittenIndex < samples.size) {
            val newData = FloatArray(mData.size + samples.size )
            mData.copyInto(newData, 0, 0, startIndex)
            samples.copyInto(newData, startIndex)
            mData.copyInto(newData, startIndex + samples.size, startIndex)
            mData = newData
        } else {
            mData.copyInto(mData, startIndex + samples.size, startIndex, mLastWrittenIndex)
            samples.copyInto(mData, startIndex)
        }
        mLastWrittenIndex += samples.size
    }

    fun getSamplesSize(): Int = mLastWrittenIndex
}
```

And here is my code for the channel based on List:

```
class Channel {

    private var mData = mutableListOf<Float>()

    fun getSamples(startIndex : Int = 0, endIndex : Int = mData.size) : List<Float>
        = mData.slice(IntRange(0, endIndex - 1))

    fun insertSamples(samples : List<Float>, startIndex : Int = mData.size) {
        mData.addAll(startIndex, samples)
    }

    fun getSamplesSize() : Int = mData.size
}
```

Here is the measuring code:

```
    val initialValuesArray = FloatArray(1000000) {Random.nextFloat()}
    val valuesToAddArray = FloatArray(1000000) {Random.nextFloat()}
    val initialValuesList = MutableList(1000000) {Random.nextFloat()}
    val valuesToAddList = MutableList(1000000) {Random.nextFloat()}

    var startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val arrayChannel = ArrayChannel()
    arrayChannel.insertSamples(initialValuesArray)
    arrayChannel.insertSamples(valuesToAddArray, 0)
    println("Array time: ${System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime}")

    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val listChannel = Channel()
    listChannel.insertSamples(initialValuesList)
    listChannel.insertSamples(valuesToAddList, 0)
    println("List time: ${System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime}")
```

Now, the average results from a direct `fun main()` call in Android studio are as following:

```
Array time: 56
List time: 6
```

A change in the allocation of the array, instead of `mData.size + samples.size` to `mData.size + samples.size * 2`, makes these different, in a very weird way:

```
Array time: 17
List time: 48
```

When I run the same code inside of an Activity instead of some main Kotlin function, the results match more what I was expecting and are promising:

```
2020-08-17 21:15:33.325 D/ARRAY_TIME: 15
2020-08-17 21:15:33.481 D/LIST_TIME: 156
```

Why the code behaves this way and what do you think would be a good way of handling lots of numerical data in the Android environment?

Comment: This is not a valid way to benchmark. It ignores warm-up time and other factors. Look for a benchmarking library. Not that you should need a benchmark to prove that a `FloatArray` doesn't suffer from boxing like a `List<Float>` does. Depending on what you're doing with it, you may find that a `FloatBuffer` constructed from a *direct* `ByteBuffer` performs even better than the `FloatArray`.

Comment: I will look into these benchmarking libraries, and definitely try `FloatBuffer` out. Additionally, I have been able to resolve some memory issues with sane arrays allocation (who would've guessed ;) ) and so far I'm pleased with the results. Thanks for the help!